# QTP read webtable content

Tags: vbscript, qtp

I have a WebTable in QTP like:

```
<TBODY>
  <TR></TR>
  <TR>
    <TD>
      <TABLE>
        <TR>
          <TD>
            <DIV class=divRow id=divRow_d_0>
              <DIV class=divFirst>1</DIV>
              <DIV class=divData>toto</DIV>
              <DIV class=divData>fofo</DIV>
            </DIV>
            <DIV class = divRow id=divRow_d_1>
              <!--same structure here-->
            </DIV>
          </TD>
        </TR>
      </TABLE>
    </TD>
  </TR>
  <TR></TR>
</TBODY>
```

Here, I want to capture the values divFirst and divData for each divRow, ideally, store every divRow in a string.

Could someone please tell me how can I do that?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
Set RowDesc = Description.Create()
RowDesc("class").Value = "divRow"
RowDesc("index").Value = 0

Set DataDesc = Description.Create()
DataDesc("class").Value = "divData"

While Browser("Browser").Page("Page").WebElement(RowDesc).Exist(1)
    Set Row  = Browser("Browser").Page("Page").WebElement(RowDesc)
    RowDesc("index").Value = RowDesc("index").Value  + 1
    MsgBox Row.WebElement("class:=divFirst").GetROProperty("innertext")
    DataDesc("index").Value = 0

    While Row.WebElement(DataDesc).Exist(1)
        Set Datum = Row.WebElement(DataDesc)
        MsgBox Datum.GetROProperty("innertext")
        DataDesc("index").Value = DataDesc("index").Value + 1
    Wend
Wend
```

The reason I'm using descriptive programming with an index that will run out is that `ChildObjects` does not return these `WebElements`

(Obviously you will want to do something other than MsgBox with the values.)

Comment: Thanks, the index works, in fact I was trying to get WebElements but no succeeded, thanks